# Pentaho repository import missing database connections

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I am trying to migrate my kettle repositories from one server A to server B. I have exported a repository from Server A as `ServerA.XML`. I imported the `ServerA.XML` to server B.

The import is finished and all the `KTR, KJB` files are available in the server B now. My problems in the server A the database connections are declared which you can see from

`Tools->Repository->Explore->Connections`. I could see that in the server A. But after exporting the `ServerA.XML` to server B. I am not able to see the database connection details in `Tools->Repository->Explore->Connections`

What am i missing here?

Comment: This is closed. Found the answer after trying couple of times

Comment: It's is always good to share your answer!